# understanding the usage of $.resolve in animateSlider.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through the code of animateSlider.js and came across the following line of code:

```
animDuration:   function(page)
        {
            var $slideAnimations            =   this.slides.eq(page);
            var slideAnimationsCount        =   $slideAnimations.children("*.animated").length;
            var animationStart              =   +new Date();

            // DIFF :: understand what $.Deferred() is used for ?
            var promise                     =   new $.Deferred();
            var animationTime,count         =   0;
            $slideAnimations.on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd",function()
                {
                    var animationEnd    =   +new Date();
                    animationTime       =   Math.ceil((animationEnd -animationStart)/1000)*1000;
                    count++;
                    if (count == slideAnimationsCount)
                    {
                        // DIFF :: understand what resolve is used for ?
                        promise.resolve(animationTime);
                    }
                });
            return promise;
        }
```

The above function gets called like so:

```
    this.animDuration(page).done(function(animationTime)
```

Now my question is how does the parameter animationTime get passed to the done() function ?

if i walk through the code , there is a new instace of deffered created like so:

```
var promise =   new $.Deferred();
```

and than there is the following like:

```
promise.resolve(animationTime);
```

resolve is passed the `animationTime` parameter and than promise is returned like so:

```
return promise;
```

But i am still not quite understanding who is passing the `animationTime` to the done() function ,can somebody explain this please ?

The line of code in concern can be seen **[HERE](https://github.com/Vchouliaras/jquery.animateSlider.js/blob/master/src/jquery.animateSlider.js#L204)**.

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [promise model of asynchronous programming](https://www.promisejs.org/). While it has become part of the [language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), what you are seeing is the [jQuery implementation of this interface](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). If you read all of those references, you will understand its use in your case.

However, to give you a primer, consider this classic `$.ajax` function

```
$.ajax({url: ..., success: function(animationTime){} });
```

Ask yourself "What is passing animationTime" to the success callback? Would it then be hard to imagine the code above in this form

```
$.ajax1({url: ...}).on('success', function(animationTime){});
```

And it's a small step from that to

```
$.ajax2({url: ...}).success(function(animationTime){})
```

isn't it? :) And that all there is to promise. It implements an interface, sometimes called `thennable` which has functions like `done`, to allow you to chain async computations.

Comment: @Alexander Solonik you need to understand that promisejs is an idea, or specification. jQuery's deferred is an implementation. Node's promise is another.

Comment: I get that i would really like to understand the plain vanilla JS dialect , and not node.js or jQuery implementation .. pls explain it in vanilla.js terms !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik your question was about $.resolve... This is a good article to start https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises. In any case, there isn't vanilla js promise without 3rd party library in ES5. You can learn about it in ES6 here: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise